# Unable to create a constant value of type 'T'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

Tags: entity-framework-4, many-to-many, ef-code-first

I see alot of question about this error, but some one can tell me why I get this error in my code?
I have the User and Group in my app, they have many to many relationship:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int GId { get; set; }

    public string GName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Members { get; set; }

    public Group()
    {
        Members = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }
}
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public UserProfile()
    {
        Groups = new HashSet<Group>();

    }
}
```

I want to get all the Group that a User has Join ans pass it to a ViewBag, so:

```
UserProfile user = core.Profiles.Find(1);
//ok, no error in controller, but view...
ViewBag.JoinGroups = core.Groups.Where(g => g.Members.Contains(user));
```

But I get the error at View:

```
@if (ViewBag.JoinGroups != null)
{
    foreach (var g in ViewBag.JoinGroups)//My issue start here
    {
        <p>@g.GId</p>
    }
}
```

And it said:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Model.UserProfile'.
>   Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported
>   in this context.

Do I missing any thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is clear: EF Linq queries do not support passing entities.

You can work around it by changing this piece:

```
UserProfile user = core.Profiles.Find(1);
ViewBag.JoinGroups = core.Groups.Where(g => g.Members.Contains(user));
```

For this:

```
ViewBag.JoinGroups = core.Groups.Where(g => g.Members.Select(x => x.UserId)
                                                     .Contains(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to a `ViewBag` or anything. It's just the deferred execution pitfall: not until the `foreach` is the query executed. You would have seen the exception earlier by doing `core.Groups.Where(g => g.Members.Contains(user)).ToList();`.

By the way you pose it is clear that you already know that [referencing non-scalar variables is not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx) in entity framework, but allow me to mention it for the sake of completeness.